# Application closes after launch during UI testing

Tags: android, gradle, junit4, android-espresso

I am trying to run UI testing on an android application with espresso but when I run the test on a mobile device or an emulator the application opens and suddenly it closes itself way to fast, even before the test is ran.

It is not that the application is crashing, it just closes as soon as it opens only when a test is ran. I am not sure what I am missing in the test configuration that provokes this behavior.

this is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test1"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.1.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.0.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is my test

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class PAC4Testing {


@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<BookListActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        BookListActivity.class);


@Test
public void checkLoadedList() {
   if (getRVcount() > 0){
        assertEquals(9,getRVcount());
    }
}

private int getRVcount(){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) mActivityRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.book_list);
    return recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
}

@Test
public void checkMenuOpened() {

}

@Test
public void checkLoadedWebViewFromDetail() {

}
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT these are logs, there is an error when the test is ran because the application closes, the test cant find anything on the screen.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int 

android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.getItemCount()' on a null object reference
at PAC4Testing.getRVcount(PAC4Testing.java:34)
at PAC4Testing.checkLoadedList(PAC4Testing.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:433)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:375)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1886)
```

Comment: Logs? Error messages on the screen or in the logs if any?

Comment: I added the error that is on the log but it didn't help me since it just refers to a null pointer that happens because since the application closes there is nothing on the screen when the test is ran. But even if I run an empty test the behavior is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly states that the `recyclerView.getAdapter()` call in `getRVcount()` is returning `null`. And that is because even though you do get the view from `RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) mActivityRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.book_list);` the recyclerview that you get isn't the same as in the class since it is a fresh one and as no Adapters or LayoutManagers associated with it. As a result you can't call `getItemCount()` on the adapter.

I am not sure what exactly are you trying to test here since you haven't posted the class' code but here are a couple of links you might want to take a look at and see if they are of any help to you https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/04/15/espresso-testing-recyclerviews/ and http://alexander-thiele.blogspot.in/2016/01/espresso-ui-tests-and-recyclerview.html

Answer (score 0):

You should never query the state of the UI from the `Instrumentation` thread during the test execution as it does not provide any synchronization with the main thread.

Instead, you should use espresso `ViewMatcher`s or implement your own matcher if you need to query the state. Espresso has a built-in main thread synchronization that will ensure that all updates to the UI have finished before returning the result.

Here is the example of the matcher that returns the number of items:

```
    fun hasCount(expectedCount: Int): Matcher<View> =
        object : BoundedMatcher<View, RecyclerView>(RecyclerView::class.java) {
            var actualCount = -1

            override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
                if (actualCount > -1) {
                    description.apply {
                        appendText("$expectedCount number of items in RecyclerView")
                        appendText("\n But $actualCount")
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun matchesSafely(recyclerView: RecyclerView): Boolean {
                actualCount = recyclerView.adapter.itemCount

                return actualCount == expectedCount
            }
        }
```

And the usage of it is like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView)).check(matches(hasCount(5)))
```